# Error : "filt_Thermal.expression is not a function"

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to create a simple mathematical formula (Thermal Condition Index - TCI creation) but I get an error message "filt_Thermal.expression is not a function"

Below is a part of the code script.

Any Ideas?

```
////////////  TCI CREATION ///////////////////////

// mask areas with no null values on Thermal band //

var Therm = L4578.select('Thermal');
var filt_Thermal = Therm.filterMetadata('Thermal',"not_contains",null); //****Thermal no null data*****//

var MinT = filt_Thermal.reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
var MaxT = filt_Thermal.reduce(ee.Reducer.max());

print(filt_Thermal);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Compute TCI using an expression.///////
var TCI = filt_Thermal.expression(
  "((MaxT - Thermal) / (MaxT + MinT))", {
  'Thermal': filt_Thermal.select('Thermal'),
  'MaxT': MaxT,
  'MinT': MinT });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `filt_Thermal` is an image collection and the function `.expression()` is taking an `ee.Image()` object as an input argument.

You could build a function that you itirate over all the images in your collection like:

```
var Indices = function(img){
 var Thermal= img.select('Thermal')
 var MinT = img.reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
 var MaxT = img.reduce(ee.Reducer.max());

 var tci= ee.Image(img).expression(
           "float((MaxT - Thermal) / (MaxT + MinT))",
          { 
              'temp': Thermal,
              'max': ee.Image.constant(maxTemp).reproject(img.projection()),
              'min': ee.Image.constant(minTemp).reproject(img.projection())
          }).rename('ndti');  
    return img.addBands(tci.rename('tci'))
})
var addTCI = filt_Thermal.map(Indices)
```

script is not tested so might be some typos in there.